# Increasing the circle radius on google map by a scrollable bar

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yii2-basic-app

I am using a google map in one of my project in which i am creating a radius around the current location of the user. Also the user must be able to increase the radius of the circle according to him.

what i was able to done is to place a another marker which on draaged by the user incease the radius of the circle.

But what i want is that there must be a scrollable bar to increase the radius of the circle.As it will provide a more user friendly interface to user to increase the radius. 
any suggestion will be most welcomed  my code is below

```
 function init() {
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng( 30.356625899999994, 78.08492950000004);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    'zoom':12 ,
    'center': mapCenter,
    'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// Create a draggable marker which will later on be binded to a
// Circle overlay.
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.356625899999994, 78.08492950000004),
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Drag me!'
});


// Add a Circle overlay to the map.
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 5000 // 5 km
});

// Since Circle and Marker both extend MVCObject, you can bind them
// together using MVCObject's bindTo() method.  Here, we're binding
// the Circle's center to the Marker's position.
// http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MVCObject
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
}

// Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Comment: Any link or something related to my requirement which i can change accordingly. will also be most welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a slider (id=myslide) and change the radius

```
$("#myslide").slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "min",
  max: 3000,
  min: 100,
  value: 500,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    updateRadius(circle, ui.value);
  }
});

function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
  circle.setRadius(rad);
}
```

jQuery UI slider: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

In your case

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   ....
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  .. 
</head>
<body>

<div id="myslider"></div>

<script>
$( "#myslider" ).slider();
</script>



<script>
var circle;

function init() {
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng( 30.356625899999994, 78.08492950000004);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    'zoom':12 ,
    'center': mapCenter,
    'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// Create a draggable marker which will later on be binded to a
// Circle overlay.
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.356625899999994, 78.08492950000004),
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Drag me!'
});


// Add a Circle overlay to the map.
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 5000 // 5 km
});

// Since Circle and Marker both extend MVCObject, you can bind them
// together using MVCObject's bindTo() method.  Here, we're binding
// the Circle's center to the Marker's position.
// http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MVCObject
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
}


$("#myslide").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    max: 3000,
     min: 100,
    value: 500,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        updateRadius(circle, ui.value);
    }
});

function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
    circle.setRadius(rad);
}

// Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @scaisEdge can you please tell me ho to implement it with my above js

Comment: @scaisEdge don't know why but now its not displaying anything.

Comment: @rahulsnegi Did you include jQuery and jQuery UI (at least the slider)? Did you create the `#myslide` element? And yes look in the console for errors. That always helps!

Comment: I have updated the answer with also the reference for JQuery UI and the myslide div for slider.. hope the JQuery are already available otherwise .. i will add these too.

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry for that silly mistake, yes i do forget to include jQuery. Now Everything is working fine And thanks once again.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank-you as well for being so supportive. being a newbie may bother you again hope you will not mind